# How To Highlight a Route on a Map?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

I Followed Microsoft Docs for Highlighting a Route on a Map . It worked perfectly on an independent project , I'm getting the Latitude and the Longitude from a JSON file , and it worked , but when I tried to integrate it in my main project it didn't work .

Here's some parts of my code :

The Page Code :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:interface_test;assembly=interface_test"
             x:Class="interface_test.MapPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <local:CustomMap x:Name="customMap" MapType="Street" WidthRequest="{x:Static local:App.ScreenWidth}" HeightRequest="{x:Static local:App.ScreenHeight}" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace interface_test
{
    public partial class MapPage1 : ContentPage
    {
        public MapPage1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i < JSONData.GetGlcLatitude1().Count; i++)
            {
                customMap.RouteCoordinates.Add(new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(JSONData.GetGlcLatitude1()[i], JSONData.GetGlcLongitude1()[i]));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < JSONData.GetGlcLatitude2().Count; i++)
            {
                customMap.RouteCoordinates.Add(new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(JSONData.GetGlcLatitude2()[i], JSONData.GetGlcLongitude2()[i]));
            }

            customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(JSONData.GetGlcLatitude1()[0], JSONData.GetGlcLongitude1()[0]), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
            double lat = JSONData.GetiviLatitude();
            double lon = JSONData.GetiviLongitude();
            var position1 = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(lat, lon);

            var pin1 = new Pin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = position1,
                Label = "Current Position",
                Address = ""
            };

            customMap.Pins.Add(pin1);
        }
    }
}
```

CustomMap Class to get the list of the points :

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace interface_test
{
    public class CustomMap : Map
    {
        public List<Position> RouteCoordinates { get; set; }

        public CustomMap ()
        {
            RouteCoordinates = new List<Position> ();
        }
    }
}
```

With this code , I only get the pin , but not the highlight route that I get in my test code : 
![screenshot]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th8m3.jpg

Comment: Those red lines are your route, are they not?

Comment: @SushiHangover yes they are , but the screenshot is from my test App , not the main one